# Using CsvHelper can I translate white space to a nullable?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, csv, csvhelper

I have some really lame Csv files I need to parse.  I am using CsvHelper and it is working awesome.  Except I have some lines that have whitespace where normaly I have a double.

File:

> Text,SomeDouble,MoreText
>
> "Good",1.23,"Good"
>
> "Bad", ,"Bad"

if I try and map this into

```
public class Test
{
  [CsvField(Name = "Text")]
  public string Text { get; set; }

  [CsvField(Name = "SomeDouble")]
  public double? SomeDouble{ get; set; }

  [CsvField(Name = "MoreText")]
  public string MoreText{ get; set; }
}
```

then I get an error like this:

> CsvHelper.CsvReaderException: An error occurred trying to read a
>   record of type
>
> Row: '2' (1-based)
>
> Field Index: '1' (0-based)
>
> Field Name: 'SomeDouble'
>
> Field Value: ' '
>
> System.Exception:  is not a valid value for Double. --->
>   System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberFormatInfo numfmt)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.DoubleConverter.FromString(String value,
>   NumberFormatInfo formatInfo)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.NullableConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , ICsvReader )    at
>   CsvHelper.CsvReader.d__0`1.MoveNext()

As I see it, my options are to create a custom parser, or map my value into a string property and do the parsing there.

Are there any other options?

It would be nice if I could configure that I want to treat white space as null.

As requested, here is a code sample that reproduces the problem

```
 static class Program
    {
        public class Test
        {
            [CsvField(Name = "Text")]
            public string Text { get; set; }

            [CsvField(Name = "SomeDouble")]
            public double? SomeDouble { get; set; }

            [CsvField(Name = "MoreText")]
            public string MoreText { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create fake in memory file
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
            streamWriter.WriteLine("Text,SomeDouble,MoreText");
            streamWriter.WriteLine("Good, 1.23, Good");
            streamWriter.WriteLine("Bad, ,Bad");

            streamWriter.Flush();

            //reset the file to the begining
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            using (
                var csv =
                    new CsvReader(
                        new StreamReader(memoryStream)))
            {
                // this call will blow up with the exception.
                var records = csv.GetRecords<Test>().ToList();

                //carry on and do stuff with 'records'...
            }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code for the method that's actually failing, I'm not familiar with CSVHelper.

Comment: I have edited the question with a better example

Comment: I don't think out-of-the-package it does that, but Does this help: [custom typeconverter](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/wiki/Custom-TypeConverter)   I'm going to see if I get anywhere with it, I could use that feature too.  Please post if you find a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end I went with creating my own type converter that will treat whitespace the same as a null.

```
public class WhiteSpaceToNullableTypeConverter<T> : TypeConverter where T : struct
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof (string);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof (T?);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture,
                                       object value)
    {
        T? result = null;

        var stringValue = (string) value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue))
        {
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            result = (T)converter.ConvertFrom(stringValue.Trim());
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture,
                                     object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        var result = (T?) value;
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Apply it to your model like this

```
public class Test
{
    [CsvField(Name = "Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [CsvField(Name = "SomeDouble")]
    [TypeConverter( typeof( WhiteSpaceToNullableTypeConverter<Double> ) )]
    public double? SomeDouble{ get; set; }

    [CsvField(Name = "MoreText")]
    public string MoreText{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple way is to use `ConvertUsing()` in your `ClassMap`:

```
Map(x => x.SomeDouble)
    .ConvertUsing(row => 
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.GetField("SomeDouble")) ?
            (double?) null : 
            Convert.ToDouble(row.GetField("SomeDouble")));
```

I like to make little helper functions and call them

```
Map(x => x.SomeDouble)
    .ConvertUsing(row => GetOddballDouble(row.GetField("SomeDouble")));
```