# How to set default value

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I am trying to parse a csv file using csv helper

this is my maping class

```
sealed class CSVFileDefinitionMapFinal : CsvClassMap<CSVFileDefinitionFinal>
{ 
    public CSVFileDefinitionMapFinal()
    {
        Map(m => m.FARM_ID).Name("FRM_ID");
    }
}
```

this is my item class

```
class CSVFileDefinitionFinal
{
    public int FARM_ID { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is that the `FRM_ID` in the csv may hav `null`. so when I do the mappign above, I have an exception that null can't be transfer to integer. I am asking about if there is a way to try and catch that and set the value to -10 when it is null.

the try and catch should be in the maping class, but I couldn't know what to do after catching the exception. in other words, i couldn't know how to set **default value** to the maping object

Comment: The question does not make clear where `static` comes in.

Comment: I believe he means `default`. I edited the question to change static to default.

Answer (score 4):

You can make that property nullable and not-automatic:

```
class CSVFileDefinitionFinal
{
    private int _farmId;

    public int? FARM_ID
    {
        get { return _farmId; }
        set { _farmId = value == null ? -10 : value.Value; }
    }
}
```

Note that you need to define a `private int _farmId` member in that class.

Comment: is the name `_farmId` necessery or I can change it to `myFarmID` ?

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent: You can change it to whatever you need.

Comment: there are two errrors. 1 the semicolon after the `get` block 2 the can't explicity change `int?` to `int`

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent: See update. Not sure about the second error. When do you get that?

Comment: after your update `value.Value` the syntax error gone. now let me test the application to see if the results are correct. +1

Comment: I noticed something. the file is `xlsx` not `csv` :( so is the reading approach the same? or not?

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent: Not sure about that, since it depends on what CsvHelper can do. However, as long as it can deserialize to object the property will still work.

Comment: your code works when there are null values, but through exception when the value are empty. can you modify your code to deal with empty values please?

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent: I'm afraid that is also about CsvHelper and the conversion should happen way before the value reaches the property. After a short search turns out you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058269/using-csvhelper-can-i-translate-white-space-to-a-nullable

Comment: `set { _farmId = value ?? -10; }` This way is tidy and simple.

Answer (score 4):

You can just add a default to the mapping.

```
Map(m => m.FARM_ID).Name("FRM_ID").Default( -10 );
```