# SQL bulkCopy writes empty string instead NULL

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, .net-core

I have function that inserts new values into database:

```cs
public async Task BulkAdd(IDataReader data)
{
    if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Broken || Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        await Connection.OpenAsync();
    }
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(Connection))
    {
        bulk.DestinationTableName = GetTableName();
        bulk.BatchSize = BATCH_SIZE;
        bulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 0; // for infinity write 0
        bulk.EnableStreaming = true;
        await bulk.WriteToServerAsync(data);
    }
}
```

insert strings are generated in order and look like:
`,,11111,,7,,620,7 11111,04/15/2013 00:00:00,false,Bulgaria,` and then are converted to `CsvDataReader`:

```
var csvStreamReader = MapDataExtraWithHeaders(reader, clientId, dataExtraHeadersMap, delimiter, uploadDataId, dateFormat);
using (var csv = new CsvReader(csvStreamReader))
{
    csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = null;
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = delimiter;
    

// ADDED
csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<string>(new EmptyAsNullConverter());

    var dataReader = new CsvDataReader(csv);
      csv.ReadHeader();
       if (!HeadersValid(csv.Context.HeaderRecord, DataHeaders))
             throw new CvtException(CVTExceptionCode.Import.InvalidHeaders);
   await _transactionsDataRepository.BulkAdd(dataReader);
}
```

I added null constraints like:

```
alter table [dbo].[Extra] add constraint [DF_Custom] default (null) for [Custom]
```

however when I look into what was added I see that instead of *NULL*, empty string was added. How can that be fixed?

Comment: What CSV library do you use? Maybe you have a option on column to read empty value as null.

Comment: Can you add the line where `CsvDataReader` is passed to `BulkAdd`?

Comment: Can you precise that CSV library do you use?

Comment: I am using https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper @Vernou

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364205/how-to-convert-empty-string-to-null-while-reading-csv-records

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom converter to convert empty to null :

```cs
public class EmptyAsNullConverter : CsvHelper.TypeConversion.StringConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return null;
        else
            return base.ConvertFromString(text, row, memberMapData);
    }
}
```

Credit to [brandonw](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/252#issuecomment-47371945)

Example of use :

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var text =
        "a,b,c,e,f" + Environment.NewLine +
        "a,,c,e,f" + Environment.NewLine +
        "a,b,c,,f";
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StringReader(text), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<string>(new EmptyAsNullConverter());
        while(csv.Read())
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"{csv.GetField<string>(i) ?? "null"}\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Output :

```
a       b       c       e       f
a       null    c       e       f
a       b       c       null    f
```

Comment: Can you look at my change? I added this line `        csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<string>(new EmptyAsNullConverter());` but it doesn't get triggered .... and values still are written as strings

Answer (score 1):

you can bind CSV to class and write a converter for it.

```
public class EmptyStringConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object StringToField(string sourceString)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceString))
            return null;
        return sourceString;
    }
}

[FieldConverter(typeof(EmptyStringConverter))]
public string MyStrField;
```